# Google Earth Engine: User memory limit exceeded error when try to reduce and build a multiband imagecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, multi-band, reducers, memoryerror

I have a long imagecollection of **Landsat-5** images from **1984** to **2011**.
This imagecollection was cropped in a smaller ROI, bit flags and scaling factors applied and for each image two new bands were calculated,  **NDVI** and **NDWI**.

Next, I'm trying to calculate a new image collection which will consist of the *max* NDVI and *median* NDWI for each year of the initial image collection.

Unfortunately I get the error:

> ImageCollection (Error) User memory limit exceeded

I also tried to minimize the memory footprint by converting the *max* and *median* images toByte but the error still occurs.

For **shorter** timeseries (for example 1984-2000) the imagecollection is generated without problem.

This is the function that I'm using:

```
//Function: Calculate max NDVI and median NDWI for each year

var annual_max_NDVI_median_NDVI =  ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1984, 2011).map(function (year){
  var date_start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  var date_end = date_start.advance(1, "year");
  
  var image1 = NDVI5
        .select('ndviNorm')
        .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.max(),16).rename('NDVI')
        .set({year: year, 'system:time_start':date_start.millis()})
        .set({year: year, 'system:time_end':date_end.millis()});
        
  var image2 = NDVI5
        .select('NDWI')
        .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.median(),16).rename('NDWI')
        .set({year: year, 'system:time_start':date_start.millis()})
        .set({year: year, 'system:time_end':date_end.millis()});

  var image = image1.addBands(image2)
  
  return(image);
}));
```

Comment: Add a filterBounds, so you're not processing 10 million images.

Comment: I have already done this with `.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(ROI))`